# Java web service, xsd date instead of dateTime

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, jax-rpc

In Java EE 1.4 using JAX-RPC 1.1, how can i expose web service, so the wsdl has a complex type (person) where one of the properties of the person is a date which is shown in the WSDL/XSD as only a date (such as a birthdate) instead of a dateTime (where the time is not wanted) in the WSDL/XSD?

i would like the xsd referenced in the wsdl to have

```
<xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:date"/>
```

instead of

```
<xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
```

java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date both seem to cause the xsd datatype to be dateTime when rendered in in wsdl/xsd.

I know java EE 1.4 doesnt have the annotations like java EE 5, but is there any way to tell the web service to use the xs:date datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually did figure out how to do this properly.

in the WEB-INF/wsdl/(schemaname).xsd I changed the datatype to date from dateTime and redeploy the service and it works with my existing java.util.Calendar types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to achieve this, JAX-RPC just doesn't have the flexibility (which is why it was killed in JavaEE 5).

In general, I usually find that WSDL generators do not have the expressive power to generate the exact WSDl I want, and so I tend to use them to generate a WSDL as a starting point, and then modifying the result. You then server up the WSDL as a static file rather than as a generated one. It's not ideal, but it's not a big deal either.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [IBM docs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wbsehelp/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.bse.doc/bse/i_bse_r_datasupported.html) you are right, both date and dateTime map to Calendar. There doesn't seem to be a standard way to use only the date part, of course you could [roll your own](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/29286/0/page/1) (interestingly the second page of the referenced article says date is for dates only but page 3 confirms it maps to Calendar).

For reference there's a similar question about [doing this in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776534/how-to-generate-xsdate-in-wcf-operationcontract-parameter).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is helpful, but doesn't directly help me solve my problem of how to make the web service expose a wsdl with an xs:date field.  The client application requested that the wsdl expose a date only, not dateTime.