# How to add timezone information to DateTime of a SOAP request

Tags: c#, datetime, soap, wsdl, timezone

I have an endpoint that based on some WSDL receives requests and builds the response object, problem is that i have a DateTime field that I have to fill with a value. When I fill this value with DateTime.Now what I see in SoapUI is the following that is correct:

> 2015-10-13T16:22:34.2701373+02:00

Meanwhile when I fill the field with a DateTime that is retrieved by the logic I have this that is wrong:

> 2015-10-05T11:40:08

Since I need the full information as it's returned in when filled by DateTime.Now what is missing and how can I add it to a DateTime object?

Comment: See `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Or try setting the `Kind` of the `DateTime` to Local

Comment: I have found strange workaround that makes exactly what I need:

DateTime completeTime = DateTime.Parse(originalTime.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

This returns exactly what i need in the SoapUI reply:
2015-10-05T13:40:08+02:00

Thank you for support

Answer (score 4):

"Use `DateTimeOffset`" is usually good advice, but part of the problem can be that when classes are auto-generated from WSDL (either with WCF or .asmx) , the `xs:DateTime` types in XSD get created as `DateTime` objects.  So - can't.

Unfortunately, there is no good solution for this.  If you actually try to use `DateTimeOffset` in your models at the source, the WSDL gets a weird complex object.  If you try to just change the receiving side, it can't deserialize an `xs:DateTime` into a `DateTimeOffset`.

This is a weakness of WCF, SOAP, and XSD.  Read more in [WCF DateTimeOffset compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9172380/634824).

The only workarounds when populating the data are to have the `DateTime` fields explicitly set to either local or UTC kind.  You can use `DateTime.SpecifyKind`, or any of the conversion functions such as `ToLocalTime`, `ToUniversalTime`, or similar methods from `TimeZoneInfo`.  Just be very careful if you decide to use local time, as taking the time zone from the server is usually not a great idea.  It would be best to transmit in terms of universal time.

If you're just filling it with the current time, then use `DateTime.UtcNow`.  If you're loading a UTC-based `DateTime` from your database, then use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` with `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  If you already have a `DateTimeOffset`, then you can use the `.UtcDateTime` property to assign it to a `DateTime` value in your model.

If `DateTimeOffset` were supported properly, then the offset could be arbitrarily anything.  But since it's not - you're limited to what you can express with `DateTimeKind`.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimeOffset : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx
this will solve your problem!

Answer (score -1):

DateTime value filled in code should have Kind property equal Local or Utc.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind(v=vs.110).aspx