# WCF Desrialization of date with offset

Tags: wcf, deserialization

I am facing an issue where wcf response contains datetime stamp as

1978-05-20T11:12:00+2:00

I want to retrieve the response as the same like 1978-05-20T11:12:00.

Please note, this offset (+02:00 in the above example) value might change for different response.  So value might be

1978-05-20T11:12:00+2:00

1978-05-20T11:12:00+5:00

1978-05-20T11:12:00+6:00

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172380/wcf-datetimeoffset-compatibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did to fix this...

update the wsdl file from

```
<xs:element name="start" type="xs:date"/>
```

to

```
<xs:element name="start" type="xs:string"/>
```

and generated the proxy.. now  the returned value with using this proxy was like 1978-05-20T11:12:00+2:00 in start field. they I used string function to extract  just the desired part.

Alternatively, proxy file can be updated from

```
[XmlAttribute( type = "Date", ElementName = "start" )]  
    public DateTime start {  
..

    }
```

to

```
[XmlAttribute( type = "string", ElementName = "start" )]  
    public string start {  
...

    }
```